# c# - How to store json data into MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, json

I have this JSON data on my REST API and I want to store it in my MySQL server

**JSON Data**

```
[
    {
        "res_order_num": "1",
        "menu_code": "1",
        "menu_quantity": "2",
        "menu_total_price": "60",
        "res_no": "1",
        "menu_name": "Adobo Manok"
    },
    {
        "res_order_num": "2",
        "menu_code": "5",
        "menu_quantity": "2",
        "menu_total_price": "90",
        "res_no": "1",
        "menu_name": "Pritong Bangus"
    }
]
```

So how do I store it in my MySQL.

Comment: Is you have any error while saving data? or do you have any code done so far?

Comment: @ropenrom pls describe the question well

Comment: I have this code on my windows form c#  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://example/Restserver/index.php/users/view");

                var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Member>>(response);

                load_1 = persons.Count;
                dataGridMember.DataSource = persons;

Comment: @ropenrom24, the above code you shown is for fetching data from api and display in `datagridview` ? Is you have to fetch json data from api or give it to api to database save ?

Comment: Yes Sir, it fetch json data and display it in DataGridview. What want to know is how to store it directly on my local database instead of displaying on datagridview

Comment: @ropenrom24, just remove this line `dataGridMember.DataSource = persons;` and call your database save method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the solution:

```
var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Member>>(response);
```

now you can loop through items like below.

```
foreach(Member person in persons )
{
    // add to db your each person
}
```

and here how you can insert to db :
for ADO.Net : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx

for EntityFramework : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712907(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: ,if json have 1000 persons then foreach iterate 1000 times and 1000 times database call so this require too much execution time and database trip

Comment: @ershoaib you can open `connection` and add you 1000 record then close in Ado.Net and in EF just after `foreach` u call `SaveChanges();`.

Comment: No no this takes 1000 round trip to database, i think it good to use bulk insert

Answer (score 1):

If your json contains from 0.....N number of persons then `BatchUpdate` is good solution for you this may reduce your database round trip if you have performance requirement

The following method contains sample of `BatchUpdate`

```
public void BatchUpdateToMySqlServer()
{
    var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Member>>(response);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("res_order_num", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("menu_code", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("menu_quantity", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("menu_total_price", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("res_no", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("menu_name", typeof(System.String)));

    foreach (var item in persons)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["res_order_num"] = item.res_order_num;
        dr["menu_code"] = item.menu_code;
        dr["menu_quantity"] = item.menu_quantity;
        dr["menu_total_price"] = item.menu_total_price;
        dr["res_no"] = item.res_no;
        dr["menu_name"] = item.menu_name;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Your Connection String");
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Your Insert Command", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    da.InsertCommand = cmd;
    da.UpdateBatchSize = 100000; //If you json contains 100000 persons object;
    int records = da.Update(dt);
    con.Close();
}
```

[Here](https://jishnutkl.wordpress.com/tag/mysql-bulk-insert-from-c-net/) is good article if you have to use `StoedProcedure` as insert command.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information; it doesn't appear you have much existing code. If you're trying to get started with saving data to a MySQL database in c#; Microsoft provides this tutorial. However there's not much people can do to answer this question without additional info.

Tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f92s97z.aspx

People might be able to give better answers if you include the following:

- Do you have existing code in place that reads or writes to MySQL?
- Do you have a MySQL database set up?
- Does your database have tables that match the data represented in the JSON?

Comment: Yes sir I have a MySQL database set up on localhost and the database tables matches the JSON data.